# PYQT4 - How do I compile and import a qrc file into my program?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, resource-files

I'm having trouble importing a resource file. I'm using pyqt4 with monkey studio and I am trying to import a png image. When I run the program I get an import error like

> ImportError: No module named icon_rc

I know that I have to compile it using pyrcc4 but I don't understand how to do this can anybody help please. It would be very helpful to have an answer that fully explains how to compile the resource file so I can import it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Open cmd (or terminal on *nix) and run

```
pyrcc4 -py3 F:\computing\Payrollv22\icon.qrc -o icon_rc.py
```

It compiled the file successfully and I was able to import the py file into my project and run it with no problem.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the `-py3` switch is only required if you are using Python 3.x. If you are using Python 2.x, the resource file needs to be compiled without this additional switch.

Comment: @0x8BADF00D [According to the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/resources.html), the `-py3` flag will make a file that is compatible with any Python 2.6 or greater, so unless you're using a really archaic version of Python, you should always use `-py3` for future-proofing

Answer (score 21):

There really isn't much to explain here, you have a resource file (e.g. `icon.qrc`), then you call `pyrcc4 -o icon_rc.py icon.qrc` which will create a module `icon_rc.py` which you then can import in your project.

It's all documented [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/resources.html).

Comment: i just cant convert this qrc file into a py module. when i use the code in cmd    pyrcc4 -o icon_rc.py icon.qrc   it says  
pyrcc4: File does not exist 'icon.qrc'

Comment: And, does it exist in the directory wher you're running the command?

Comment: ah okay so i managed to compile it and import it into my project but it now throws up a new error!     File "<string>", line 89, in <module>
  File "F:\computing\Payrollv22\icon_rc.py", line 300, in <module>
    qInitResources()
  File "F:\computing\Payrollv22\ritch_rc.py", line 295, in qInitResources
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, str(qt_resource_struct), str(qt_resource_name), str(qt_resource_data))
TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, str, str, str): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'

Answer (score 5):

In Pyqt5 this command can be used `Pyrcc5 input_file.qrc -o Out_file.py`

We need to convert that qrc file into python file and then it can be imported to your code

Answer (score 2):

its because when you also used pyuic5 to convert your UI to py, the resource file name from the UI sticks.

then use

```
Pyrcc5 input_file.qrc -o icons.py
```

remove from main_script.py

```
import icon_rc
```

and use

```
import icons
```

the when calling the actual icons from the icons module, you have to look at your qrc file prefix.

```
< RCC >
    < qresource
    prefix = "ico5" >
    < file > plugin.png < / file >
    < / qresource >
< / RCC >
```

if prefix is ico5 
then you load icons with

```
 QtGui.QIcon(":/ico5/plugin.png")
```

and if prefix is , lets say,

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="icons">
```

then its:

```
  QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/plugin.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try with pyside as well like:

--- `pyside-rcc -o input.qrc output.py`

Comment: pyside is different to pyqt4

Comment: Yes it is, but this is just for another option.